# How can I filter on a list in Azure Synapse filter transformation mapping data flow

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

In Azure Synapse Data flows I want to filter on a list of values.

I can use the following syntax:-

`column1 == 'A' || column1 =='B'`

but would like to use something like this:-

`column1 IN ('A','B')`

How can I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This expression `column1 IN ('A','B')` can't work. Instead,you can build an array and then use this expression:

```
in(['A','B'],column1)
```

Reference:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-expression-functions#in